# Whenever i run a python program on vs code, i get this, can someone explain me in detail on how to fix it, it just annoys me

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Here is a screenshot of the error. I tried reinstalling multiple times but with no success, my programs run fine but it annoys me, I know I can put it to ignore every time but still, let me know if there is a potential fix for it.The last line is
[image: error image]

Here is my path in cmd

Path=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_271\bin;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;"C:\users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python39;C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Tools\scripts";C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts;C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39;C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts;C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;"C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39;C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Tools\scripts";C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;

I know there are inverted commas and all from nowhere but how do i remove it, i cant see it in my c path

Comment: Umm. Cannot see it

Comment: can't see screen shot

Comment: Have you tried to do what the message is telling you instead of "reinstalling"?

Comment: is it visible now? sorry i am new to stack overflow

Comment: Click on more info and remove that extension

Comment: mkreieger i couldnt find what the message is telling, there is no double inverted commas in my paths. I even typed it on my own with no success

Comment: ignore works , but i was curious if others fixed it or they just ignore it

Comment: Those double inverted commas are (single) double quote characters.

Comment: tbh, i coudnt find nor did i use any type of inverted comma in the paths, should i attach a path screenshot?

Comment: in a cmd.exe shell use `set` to see the used path

Comment: Thanks a lot rivoV8, i didnt know the command, let me now try out something.

Comment: `should [I] attach a path screenshot?` Most definitely not! Copy and paste essential *textual* information into you post - such allows telling two consecutive single quotes from a lone  double quote.

Comment: okay thanks for the tip! i will be careful next time

Answer (score 0):

Are you on windows or on Linux?

If you're on windows, you may want to change your PATH to remove paths with the "'" following more or less the descriptions here:

https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/

If you're on Linux, follow these steps:

https://stackabuse.com/how-to-permanently-set-path-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

I can see four double quote characters in your path, and that caused the problem you met.

But you say, you can't find them in the system environment path.

So, have you checked the `path` in `User variables`? And it seems like something modify the system environment path, then you should find out what caused it.

You can get the path in Powershell with the command of `$env:path`, to check whether it influences Powershell. And is it the same when in the VSCode and out of it.

Comment: yes I have checked the path in user variables and it isnt visible (the inverted commas) I really dont know whats causing the issue but i just ignored it, vs code still works fine for me. Thanks for taking your time to try and hlp me out.

Comment: the commas are visible when i checked the path in cmd and powershell though.